# Multiplos filtros em um objeto json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtro, filter

Olá.

Tenho 10 filtros para um unico objeto json:

```
var filtro1 = function(value, selecionado){
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
    var result = data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return result;
}

var filtro2 = function(value, selecionado){
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
    var result = data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return result;
}

var filtro3 = function(horamin, horamax){
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
    var result = data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return result;
}

var filtro4 = function(value, selecionado){
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
    var result = data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return result;
}
...
```

E assim por diante. Como pode ver cada filtro funciona separadamente ou seja se eu filtrar com o filtro1 e depois com o filtro2 ele exibe somente o do filtro2.

Teria alguma maneira que eu consiga juntar esses filtros?

Pensei em usar um array com os filtros selecionado:

```
var filtros = ["filtro1, "filtro2", "filtro6", "filtro9", "filtro10"];
```

Mas não consegui.

A ideia e interligar os filtros.

Comment: Mas são 10 filtros que produzem 10 resultados ou deveriam ser 10 filtros que produzem 1 resultado? Como o código você apresentou 10 resultados, mas com o texto dá a entender que deveria ser apenas um. Confuso.

Comment: você quis dizer resultado = json.filter(func() ..).filter(func2() ...)... ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss São 10 filtro que produzem um resultado. Assim: Tenho um json e quero filtrar ele por cor, tamanho, quantidade, preço tudo junto. Do jeito que está eu consigo filtrar cada um separadamente. Mas preciso de somente 1 resultado

Comment: Já pensou em, no lugar de fazer `json.filter` em todos, colocar o resultado do filtro anterior? Por exemplo: `var filtro2 = filtro1.filter()`

Comment: Assim com seria também bom fazer um array com as funções de filtro todas aplica-las com um ciclo, usando sempre o resultado da iteração anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro, você pode estruturar os seus filtros dentro de uma "Classe".

```
var Filtro = function () {
    this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json.aPesquisa));
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro1 = function(value, selecionado){
    this.data = this.data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro2 = function(value, selecionado){
    this.data = this.data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro3 = function(horamin, horamax){
    this.data = this.data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro4 = function(value, selecionado){
    this.data = this.data.filter(function(pesquisa){
        ...
    });
    return this;
}

...

Filtro.prototype.GetResult = function() {
    return this.data;
}
```

você pode chamar ele da seguinte forma.:

```
var result = new Filtro()
    .filtro1(value1, selected1)
    .filtro2(value2, selected2)
    .filtro6(horamin, horamax) 
    .filtro9(value9, selected9) 
    .filtro9(value10, selected10) 
    .GetResult();
```

ou da seguinte forma.:

```
var filtros = [
    { name: "filtro1", params: [ value1, selected1 ] }, 
    { name: "filtro2", params: [ value2, selected2 ] }, 
    { name: "filtro6", params: [ horamin, horamax ] }, 
    { name: "filtro9", params: [ value9, selected9 ] },  
    { name: "filtro10", params: [ value10, selected10 ] }
]; 
var result = filtros.reduce(function (wrapper, filtro) {
    return wrapper[filtro.name].call(wrapper, filtro.params);
}, new Filtro()).GetResult();
```

Segue uma implementação com o mesmo principio.

```js
var Filtro = function () {
  this.filtros = [];
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro1 = function(value, selecionado){
  this.filtros.push({ 
    filtro: "filtro1", 
    params: {  
      value: value, 
      selecionado: selecionado
    } 
  });
  return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro2 = function(value, selecionado){
  this.filtros.push({ 
    filtro: "filtro2", 
    params: {  
      value: value, 
      selecionado: selecionado
    } 
  });
  return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro6 = function(horamin, horamax){
  this.filtros.push({ 
    filtro: "filtro6", 
    params: {  
      horamin: horamin, 
      horamax: horamax
    } 
  });
  return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.filtro9 = function(value, selecionado){
  this.filtros.push({ 
    filtro: "filtro9", 
    params: {  
      value: value, 
      selecionado: selecionado
    } 
  });
  return this;
}

Filtro.prototype.GetResult = function(){
  return this.filtros;
}

var result = new Filtro()
  .filtro1("value 01", "selecionado 01")
  .filtro2("value 02", "selecionado 02")
  .filtro6("horamin 06", "horamax 06") 
  .filtro9("value 09", "selecionado 09") 
  .GetResult();
console.log(result);
```